# Outlook web add-in : displayDialogAsync() not working

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I can't post a working demo, because the code needs to run in MS Outlook.

I am developing based on this [Outlook Add-in Command Demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo).

I want to add a dialog box, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) in the MS docs.

I took that working demo and added one single line:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://my_site.com/project/hello_world.html');
```

where `https://my_site.com/project` is where the rest of the app is, and `hello_world.html` is a bare minimal HTML file with a "Hello World" body.

I added that where I saw `Office.context` being used - in the function `insertText()` - to be sure that it had ben created.

That function is caled when a button on a task pane is clicked when composing an email.

I do not see the "Hello World" dialog, nor anything in the console log.

Is `displayDialogAsync()` not allowed from a task pane?

Any ideas from the info I can give what I might be doing wrongly, or how to detect it? Does the fucntion have a return value, or throw an exception if it fails? Any othe ideas? Is there a ***minimal*** demo, maybe just from clicking a button on the ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `displayDialogAsync` from a task pane. To troubleshoot, pass a callback parameter to the method and read the `AsyncResult.error` property. For details see [Office.ui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js) as well as the article that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult?view=office-js) i shelpful, WRT the `AsyncResult.error` property.

Comment: Btw, do you know of any really basic demo? Maybe just a ribbon button which displays an HTML page as dialog?

Comment: The example in the doc link you provided should be pretty simple. (just make sure you call it after office.initialize) You can modify it to dump out the asyncResult results to track down what the error is. Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20},
    function (asyncResult) {
      showMessage(JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
    }
);

Comment: The most common type of error here is that the URL that you are trying to go to is not included in the AppDomains section of your manifest.